# YAML load is not interpreting every variable correctly

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have some code trying to load some variables to a hangman game i'm making

```
begin
    yaml = YAML.load_file("./hangman.yml")
    print yaml[0].guess_array               
    print yaml[0].turn_count                
    print yaml[0].guessed_letters                
    print yaml[0].check_word                
    print yaml[0].word
end
```

but for some reason it's incorrectly loading a few variables
the guess_array yaml is

```
guess_array:
- p
- a
- n
- e
- _
- _
- _
- _
```

but when it prints out in the file I get

```
["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
```

It's also incorrectly interpreting a couple more but I'm hoping there's a mistake i'm making that will fix all of these.

Comment: According to the YAML structure you can't just access it with `0` as a key, the only key defined is `'guess_array'`. You can't access `guess_array` as a method call, or any of those other things since those methods don't exist.

Comment: Seconding tadman, this script you show will not produce the output you claim

Comment: So you're comment led me to the solution, the variables that were interpreting wrong had class methods with the same name, as soon as I changed the name of the class methods everything was interpreted correctly.